# Invalid credential 401 error when fetching google calendar events using chrome identity token

Tags: actions-on-google

I am fetching calendar event list using google api v3 and it works weird.
It returns 401 the following error.

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 401,
        "message": "Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
        "errors": [
            {
                "message": "Invalid Credentials",
                "domain": "global",
                "reason": "authError",
                "location": "Authorization",
                "locationType": "header"
            }
        ],
        "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
    }
}
```

But it works on a fresh new chrome profile, how come it is so?

I am using the code below.

```
      chrome.identity.getAuthToken({ interactive: false }, async (token) => {
        ...
      })
```

```
    const response = await fetch(
      `https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events?timeMin=${beginningOfDay.toISOString()}&timeMax=${endOfDay.toISOString()}&singleEvents=true`,
      {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${this.identityToken}`
        }
      }
    )
```